# Can't reduce padding between icon buttons in a column(Bootstrap, HTML & CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

The icon buttons are supposed to cover the same width as the dynamic table on their right side but they overflow slightly instead.
[Aproximed desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sx51.png) /
[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOlYc.png) .
Before pasting the block of code,here are some of the things i've already tried:

- Setting **padding**,**padding-bottom**,**padding-inline**,**margin**,**margin-inline** to 0px , or even negative values on margin.
- Reducing **line-height** , **height**,**max-height** or setting it to **fit-content**/**none**.
- Removing formatting spaces between **buttons** and **icons** in HTML so they're all on the same line of code.
- Using **py-0**,**px-0** and **pz-0** class from Bootstrap
- Using **display:flex , align-items:space-between**, adding **flex-direction: column**

That said, here's my code:

```css
.actions-column {
  padding: 0px;
}

.values-column {
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-11 values-column">
    <div class="row-lg containerRating list-group" id="userActCourses"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 actions-column">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-floating btn-pure">
                                          <i id="addActIcon" data-index=-1 class="fa fa-plus action-icon add" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-floating btn-pure" disabled>
                                          <i class="fa fa-pencil action-icon edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-floating btn-pure" disabled>
                                          <i class="fa fa-trash action-icon delete" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-floating btn-pure" disabled>
                                          <i id="addCompleteIcon" class="fa fa-check-square-o action-icon complete" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

### UPDATE

What worked for me was adding a custom CSS class and reducing the button size manually.

```css
.actions-column {
  padding: 0px;
}

.values-column {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.customButton{
height:3rem;  /*Lower than the default size in bootstrap*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-11 values-column">
    <div class="row-lg containerRating list-group" id="userActCourses"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 actions-column">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-floating btn-pure customButton"> <!-HERE!!!->
                                          <i id="addActIcon" data-index=-1 class="fa fa-plus action-icon add" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-floating btn-pure customButton" disabled><!-HERE!!!->
                                          <i class="fa fa-pencil action-icon edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-floating btn-pure customButton" disabled><!-HERE!!!->
                                          <i class="fa fa-trash action-icon delete" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-floating btn-pure customButton" disabled><!-HERE!!!->
                                          <i id="addCompleteIcon" class="fa fa-check-square-o action-icon complete" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is designed to be mobile first, so getting things to align vertically can be tricky. you might want to look into using the flex classes

Comment: yeah unfortunately it doesnt seem to affect it as mentioned in the last bulletpoint :(

Comment: since you're using bootstrap it's preferred not to use css overrides. try d-flex and flex-row around your first div and another d-flex flex-column around your buttons

Comment: also it might be easier to make your text area on the left taller than try and contain your buttons within the vertical space of the text area.

Comment: the d-flex option you said didnt work for this particular case but its very interesting and ill consider it in the future!

Comment: What worked for me was simply making those specific 4 buttons smaller , but ill consider what you said if i make some more of these from scratch haha ty!

Comment: try bootstrab 5 CSS variables: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
        style="--bs-btn-padding-y: .25rem; --bs-btn-padding-x: .5rem; --bs-btn-font-size: .75rem;">
  Custom button
</button>

Answer (score 0):

use position: relative;   and then you can move it around;